# Export-SPWeb temporary folder

Tags: powershell, backup, export

Anyone knows the location of temporary files that Export-SPWeb uses when exporting sites? One of our servers ran out of drive space when exporting the site and now I can't find the files created by the cmdlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the environment variable %tmp% (not %temp%).  If I remember right, Todd Klindt talked  about it in this netcast: http://toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=313.

Answer (score 3):

you can specify the path

```
export-spweb -identity http://host -path D:\Backups\file.cmp -force
```

If you do not have space on disk, you can create shared folder and give rights to write.

Comment: Or just use a drive analyse tool to find what's eating up your space. I usually use Sequoiaview: http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview/